# How to design a Custom Generic Thread class (send and recieve data) in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler

I want to make a Custom Generic Thread Class for heavy network operations.

I know how to use `AsyncTask`, been using it, but now it sometimes crashes, since `AsyncTask` is not recommended for operations which take more than 5 seconds.. And for implementing `OOP` principles (re-usability) I decided to make a separate common Thread class which all my Transaction Screens can use to send and receive data from the network ! I don't want to make a separate thread for each screen..
I searched the internet and the stackoverflow for all possible solutions...

This is what I've tried so far...

```
import mainMenu.AccountBean;
import parser.ParserMain;
import parser.ValuesBean;

public class NetworkThread implements Runnable {
private String proccessCode;
private AccountBean ab;
private ValuesBean vb;
private String[] sd;

public NetworkThread(String proccessCode, AccountBean ab, String[]sd){
    this.proccessCode = proccessCode;
    this.ab = ab;
    this.sd = sd;

}


@Override
public void run() {
    ParserMain pm = new ParserMain();
    try {
        // this method does socket based transactions..
        vb = pm.commenceTransaction(proccessCode, ab, sd); // I want this object 'vb' sent back to my activity..
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();



     }

  }

}
```

My SomeActivity's Button Listener

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NetworkThread nt = new NetworkThread("1234",ab, someOtherValuesHere);
            Handler h = new Handler();
            h.post(nt); //  <= how to get value from here
        }
    });
```

My Questions are how to get value from this `Handler` ?? I've seen many examples on `Message` but in my scenario where do I implement `Message` in Activity or the `Thread` class ? If there is another approach preferred I'm open to suggestions, Thanks.

Comment: IntentService might be worth a look. It runs for every Intent with data sent to it, but processes them one at a time. You can send data back with localbroadcast receiver.

Comment: Try intentService, they are meant to do heavy operations on network in background.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid `BroadCastListeners` and `Services` !! Any other approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't running this in a separate `Thread`, despite the fact that you've named it `NetworkThread`, it isn't a `Thread` This is running on the main (UI) thread, which isn't what you want.

Change `NetworkThread` so that it extends `Thread`, not `Runnable`. Then do this:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        NetworkThread nt = new NetworkThread("1234",ab, someOtherValuesHere);
        nt.start();
    }
```

To get data from `NetworkThread` back to the calling Activity, you could do something like this:

Declare a callback interface in `NetworkThread`:

```
public Interface NetworkThreadCallback {
    void reportData(ValuesBean vb);
}
```

and declare a member variable in `NetworkThread`:

```
private NetworkThreadCallback callback;
```

Then, in `NetworkThread` constructor, add a parameter `NetworkThreadCallback callback` and store that in the member variable `callback`. After you've successfully called `commenceTransaction`, do this:

```
callback.reportData(vb);
```

Each calling `Activity` needs to `implement NetworkThreadCallback` and have a method

```
public void reportData(ValuesBean vb) {
    // Do something with the ValuesBean here...
}
```

You just need to understand that this technique is not as robust as using a `Service`. If your process goes to the background (User presses HOME button, takes a phone call, etc.) Android can kill your process at any time. In this case your `NetworkThread` will just go away.

Comment: I want `NetworkThread` to report to the activity.. return data to the calling `Activity`

Comment: One thing I didn't understand is ... What is callback(vb); ?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. It should be `callback.reportData(vb)`. I fixed my answer.